# Removing node in Binary Search Tree (Python)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, treenode

```
def remove(self,node):

    def removerec(aroot,node):
        if node < aroot.item:
            if aroot.left == None:
                return print("Does not exist")
            return removerec(aroot.left,node)               
        elif node > aroot.item:
            if aroot.right == None:
                return print("Does not exist")
            return removerec(aroot.right,node)
        else: # When aroot.item = node

            if aroot.left == None and aroot.right == None:
                aroot = None
                return 
            elif aroot.left == None and aroot.right != None:
                aroot = aroot.right
                return
            elif aroot.right == None and aroot.left != None:
                aroot = aroot.left
                return
            else:
                if self.countChildren(aroot.left.item) > self.countChildren(aroot.right.item):
                    test = aroot.left
                    while test.right != None:
                        test = test.right
                    aroot.item = test.item
                    return removerec(aroot.left,test.item)
                else:
                    test = aroot.right
                    while test.left != None:
                        test = test.left
                    aroot.item = test.item
                    return removerec(aroot.right,test.item)



    if not self.exists(node):
        return "Does not exist"
    else:
        return removerec(self.root,node)
```

The problem is that

```
if aroot.left == None and aroot.right == None:
aroot = None
```

does not remove the node from the tree. When the node to be removed has two children it successfully changes it to the leftmost children of the right child or the rightmost children of the left child, but fails to remove the node whose value it received. I've been testing and it seems that aroot changes to None (removed), but not the node in the tree. I might be missing something obvious, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `Node` is a `Leaf`?

Comment: Yes, I might have figured it out though. By changing the node to None I forgot to remove the link to its parent, effectively leaving it in the tree.

Comment: You should just set `Parent` edge to this `Leaf` to `None`

Comment: Setting `aroot = None` has the effect of changing the value of a local variable. You should use something like `parent_of_aroot.left_or_right = None`, that is: you should modify an attribute of the parent of `aroot` for the code to have some visible effect